# Sqoop command with --query in Scala using Process("<sqoop command>").! not working

Tags: scala, shell, apache-spark, sqoop

I am trying to run a Sqoop command having *--query* option on Scala shell using `Process("<sqoop command>").!` but it is showing an error described below.

If I use *--table* instead of *--query*, it works like a charm.

But for my requirement, I need to use *--query*.

The error it gives is :

```
ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Error parsing arguments for import:  
ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: *  
ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: from
```

etc.

Thanks in advance

The below code works properly in Spark-Scala shell.

```
Process("""sqoop import <queuename> --connect <connection-string-db2> -- 
    username <username> --password <password> --table "<database.table>" -- 
    target-dir <target directory> --delete-target-dir --fields-terminated-by 
    '\\001' --lines-terminated-by '\\n' --null-string '\\\\N' --null-non- 
    string '\\\\N' --hive-drop-import-delims -m 1""").!
```

But when I change *--table* by *--query* (and use whatever basic query in it e.g. `"SELECT * FROM DATABASE.TABLE"`), it doesn't work... Below is the command which doesn't work:

```
Process("""sqoop import <queuename> --connect <connection-string-db2> -- 
    username <username> --password <password> --query "SELECT * FROM 
    DATABASE.TABLE AND \$CONDITIONS" --target-dir <target directory> -- 
    delete-target-dir --fields-terminated-by '\\001' --lines-terminated-by 
    '\\n' --null-string '\\\\N' --null-non-string '\\\\N' --hive-drop- 
    import-delims -m 1""").!
```

Comment: Instead of double quoutes( " ), use single quote( ' ) 
--query 'SELECT * FROM .TABLE AND \$CONDITIONS'

Comment: @RohitNimmala  Did that, didn't work.

Comment: Is this command working if you directly sqoop from Shell?

Comment: and I dont think you need "AND \$CONDITIONS" if you dont use where condition i.e if you want to do only select * of whole table.

Comment: @RohitNimmala Yes the sqoop command is working fine from shell..Tried & tested.

Comment: @RohitNimmala Tried removing "AND \$CONDITIONS" as well, still no luck.

Comment: Have you tried "SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM database.table"?

Comment: @Chris  I did try that.. No luck

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to escape the double quotes after --query .